# Simple UL Question Coming from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a very simple query

```
$this->db->select('id, title');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('journal');

foreach($query->result() as $row):?>
<ul>
<li><? echo anchor("journal/arc_journal/$row->id", $row->title);?></li>
</ul>
<? endforeach;?>
```

The data link it produces is perfect, but when my list is displayed it comes out like this

```
<ul> 
<li>link from above</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>link from above</li>
</ul>
```

etc.  Which means I am getting unwanted spaces between my links. My database info is normal, nothing to indicate it should do this.

I get the same type of list if I use an array and the codeigniter ul() html helper.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the below not do what you want? If not, please post expected output.

```
<?php
$this->db->select('id, title');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('journal');
?>

<ul>
foreach($query->result() as $row):?>
<li><? echo anchor("journal/arc_journal/$row->id", $row->title); ?></li>
<? endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much.  This should have been obvious to me.